# MSI for Visual C++ 2015

Tags: installation, windows-installer, redistributable

I need to install redistributable Visual C++ 2015 on three hundred computers in a corporate office. Is there any way to convert EXE to MSI. It would save tons of time.

Answer (score 5):

The Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installers are built with the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).

You can extract the contents of these with the `dark` tool:

```
+>dir /b vc_*
vc_redist.x64.exe
vc_redist.x86.exe

+>mkdir x64-extracted

+>c:\local\WiX-3.11.1-bin\dark.exe vc_redist.x64.exe -x x64-extracted
Windows Installer XML Toolset Decompiler version 3.11.1.2318
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

vc_redist.x64.exe

+>cd x64-extracted

+>dir /b /s
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\UX
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages\Patch
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages\Patch\x64
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\AttachedContainer\packages\Patch\x86
....\vcredist-2015\x64-extracted\UX
...

+>
```

This will contain the `vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi` along with a cab1.cab that contains the actual data and the `vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi` along with another `cab1.cab` with the MFC dlls.

Note that it will *also* contain a bunch of MSU files (under the `..\Patch\..`) subdir, that contain operating system patches for a minimum version of the [Universal C Runtime](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/). The UCRT is the part of the C runtime library that is no longer VS version specific, but an OS component.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for a solution for that, too but couldn't find a way.

I just deploy it with powershell with silent switch like this:

```
& "\\MyServer\path\vc_redist.x86.exe" /q /norestart | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to extract it, as in the [this example](http://www.applepie.se/extract-msi-from-visual-c-2012-redistributable)?

Comment: Yes, it does not contain MSI, just bunch of files without extension

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tool  that converts a setup executable file (EXE) into a Windows Installer Package (MSI):

**QwertyLab's Exe to Msi Converter (Free)**: [download](https://download.cnet.com/Exe-to-Msi-Converter-Free/3000-2216_4-10969236.html)

**EMCO MSI Package Builder** (Shareware): [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319012944/https://emcosoftware.com/download)
You can download and use an evaluation version during a trial period. If you would like to continue using the product after the trial period, you must purchase the license. License removes any trial version limitations, so you don't need to download another copy of the product.

MSI package are useful to be deployed via GPO of Microsoft Active Directory.

Also, There other approach than GPO using EMCO Remote Installer.

EMCO Remote Installer perform any complex deployment task with just a few clicks. The application automates software deployment and audit operations, so you can easily manage software across your entire network. Review [feature list](https://emcosoftware.com/remote-installer/feature-list)