# Crash in _snprintf_s() in "ucrtbase.dll" with STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, universal-crt

It was brought to my attention that my binary will crash on the CPU *without* SSE support, with exception code `0xC000001D` (STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION), despite I'm compiling with option `/arch:IA32`. And I have been able to track down the exact place where it crashes: Wherever **`_snprintf_s()`** is called for the first time, it will crash. The crash is inside of **ucrtbase.dll**, *not* my own code.

Now, the *interesting* part is that, when I make a "fully static" build with compiler option **`/MT`**, so to avoid explicity dependency on **ucrtbase.dll**, the resulting binary works just fine! But, as soon as I compile the exactly some code as "shared" build, with option **`/MD`**, it will crash again in  **ucrtbase.dll**.

So it would appear that "static" version of the **UCRT** still *can* work on the CPU *without* SSE support, but the "shared" (DLL) version can ***not***. This inconsistency would clearly seem like a bug to me!

Any thoughts?

---

Build environment:

- Windows 10 v1803
- Visual Studio 2017.8 (v15.8.1)
- Windows SDK v10.0.**17134**.12
- Toolset: `v141_xp`
- Compiler option: `/arch:IA32`

Test machine (used for compat-testing only):

- CPU: Pentium II
- OS: Windows XP with Service-Pack 3

**Note:** Redist DLLs (`ucrtbase.dll` +`api-ms-win-*.dll`) for the setup of the "shared" build have been copied straight from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86` directory! To the best of my knowledge, this is the latest available version of these DLLs (v10.0.17134.12).

---

Even this minimal test program will reproduce the crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[128];
    _snprintf_s(buffer, 128, _TRUNCATE, "Hello %s!\n", "World!");
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tracked down with debugger. It crashes inside of the implementation of `_snprintf_s()`, inside of system DLL `ucrtbase.dll`. The code is STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION, so almost certainly **not** a problem in my code, but use of SSE instruction in pre-existing code inside system DLL `ucrtbase.dll`. Even minimal test application with *nothing* but `main()` calling into `_snprintf_s()` will reproduce the crash! And only on CPU *without* SSE; otherwise it works fine!

Comment: Did you try with [standard `snprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)? It is available if you can use C++11.

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft as well.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano They’ll probably tell OP that Windows XP support has ended in 2014 and will do nothing. As of today, all supported versions of Windows (i.e. 8.1 and 10) require SSE.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist: Call to `snprintf()` results in the same crash as the call to `_snprintf_s()`. Looking at the callstack, it seems that they both end up in same internal routine named `_stdio_common_vsprintf` inside of **`ucrtbase.dll`** – where it crashes.

Comment: @Soonts: Nonetheless, Windows XP is still an officially supported "target" system for MSVC in VS2017. They even have a separate **`v141_xp`** toolset for exactly the purpose - which I am using. Also, the "Redist" UCRT DLL's (in Windows 10 SDK) are provided exactly for the purpose of supporting these "legacy" systems. Newer Windows versions come with the UCRT integrated. Also: If latest UCRT version stopped supporting *non*-SSE CPUs, then why only the DLL version is effected and **not** the "static" lib? This doesn't look intentionally to me. It looks like a bug to me...

Comment: @MuldeR I think they have `v141_xp` toolset because there’re couple of XP-based OSes that are still supported, Windows Embedded POSReady 2009 and Windows Embedded Standard 2009. You’re using neither of them.

Comment: @Soonts: I don't agree. I think toolset **`v141_xp`** exists to target Windows XP *in general*. The separate **`_xp`** toolsets where introduced in VS2012, long before XP became "end of life". But anyway: That's **not** the point, I think! If UCRT "officially" stopped supporting *non*-SSE CPUs, then (1) this needs to be made clear by MS somewhere and (2) the DLL version and the "static" lib should be effected equally. The way it is now, it seems like an oversight, effecting only in the DLL version...

Comment: @MuldeR The way it’s now, it seems MS no longer cares what happens when your CPU doesn’t support SSE. “the DLL version and the static lib should be effected in the same way” read the source code in `ucrt\stdio\output.cpp` under Windows SDK and you’ll see template C++ implementation of that thing, in common_vsprintf / common_vsnprintf_s / common_vsprintf_s template functions. Probably because of these templates, the static library is affected by `/arch:IA32` in your project.

Comment: @Soonts: Indeed, in MSVC's `stdio.h` header file, **`_snprintf_s()`** is defined as "inline" code. But that's really just a minimal "wrapper" function, that will call the actual function, which is `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s()`, from the UCRT. And *that* function is **not** "inlined" but rather located inside **`ucrtbase.dll`** or **`libucrt.lib`**, depending on which variant ("static" or "DLL") of the UCRT is linked in. It is also  `__stdio_common_vsnprintf_s()` where the crash occurs, in the "DLL" version.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

After some more debugging and fiddling around, I made a very interesting observation: The UCRT "Redist" DLLs contained within the  *latest* **`vcredist_x86.exe`** (Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable installer), i.e. the version that ships with VS2017.8 (v14.15.26706), are actually quite different from those UCRT "Redist" DLLs that can be found in the `Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86` directory of the *latest* **Windows SDK** (v10.0.17134.12):

- **`ucrtbase.dll`** from *latest* Windows SDK
  v10.0.17134.12
- **`ucrtbase.dll`** from *latest* Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable installer:
  v10.0.10586.15

Indeed, I can confirm now that the application compiled with *latest* Visual C++ 2017 (v14.15.26706) and using the **`/MD`** option works correctly on the *non*-SSE CPU, as long as we use the "old" **`ucrtbase.dll`** version, as extracted from the *latest* **`vcredist_x86.exe`** installer.

I'm a bit concerned using such an old version of the UCRT, if the Windows SDK already provides a much newer version. But, apparently, that is what Microsoft is doing themselves with the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable installer. So, I guess, it is what we are supposed to use...

---

**Just in case anybody at Microsoft is reading this:**

Things could have been ***way*** less confusing and error-prone for software developers, if, in the `Redist\ucrt` directory of the Windows SDK, there were separate sub-folders for each "incarnation" of the UCRT – the latest "cutting edge" version of the UCRT and the "compatible" version of the  UCRT that we are actually supposed to redistribute. If *then* somebody at Microsoft spent three minutes for writing a little README file that tells us which "incarnation" of the CRT we should pick and put it at `Redist\ucrt\README.txt`, it would be almost impossible to do wrong...

Comment: Extracting files from the VS redistributable is not quite straightforward.  Refer to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490616/731081) for procedure utilizing WiX toolset